# handling event and interchangeable state in hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have this small web app which I wrote when I was studying react, of course its in Class based components

As I learnt more I've decided to move over to hooks but I can't get my mind around it, imo I think class based components was more straightforward

So in Class based components I had my configiration as follows

State:

`this.state = { countryData: {updated:0,cases:0, todayCases:0, deaths:0, todayDeaths:0, recovered:0, active:0}}`

Setting initial state:

```
async getData(){
        const resApi = await Axios.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all')
        this.setState({ countryData : resApi.data })
}
```

`componentDidMount(){ this.getData() }`

And then I have a dropdown menu of options which on change changes the country data

```
async getCountryData(event){
        if (!event) return this.getData()
        const res = await Axios.get(`https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/${event.value}`)
        this.setState({ countryData : res.data })
}
```

So now I've tried to make the same thing in hooks I've started with

```
const [countryData, setcountryData] = useState({updated:0,cases:0, todayCases:0, deaths:0, todayDeaths:0, recovered:0, active:0})
```

Then for the previous 2 methods

```
    const useChoosenCountry = (event) => {
        useEffect(() => {
            async function getdata(event){
                if (!event) {
                    const resApi = await Axios.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all')
                    setcountryData(resApi.data)
                }
                    const res = await Axios.get(`https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/${event.value}`);
                    setcountryData(res.data);   
                } 
                console.log(event)
            getdata()
        },[event])
    }
```

But it looks like I'm really far it's not console logging the event on change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`componentDidMount` can be replaced with `useEffect(function, [])`:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getData();
}, [])


const getData = async () => {
    const res = await Axios.get('https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/all')
    setcountryData(res.data)
}

const getCountryData = async (event) => {
    if (!event) return this.getData()
    const res = await Axios.get(`https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/countries/${event.value}`)
    setcountryData(res.data)
}
```